# .NET class for holding and manipulating binary data

Tags: .net

Is there a class in the .NET BCL that can store a block of binary data and that allows you to easily add and remove bytes to/from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<byte>` doesn't serve your purpose?

Comment: Er... yes :-) Why didn't I think of that! It is not *exactly* what I need, but I could write a thin wrapper around it, so I can add functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`MemoryStream` class is exactly for that purpose. However, removing an arbitrary bloc of bytes can be trickier